# disable drawer toggler touch

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

THis is the code of my navigation drawer:

```
   RelativeLayout drawer_wrapper = findViewById(R.id.drawer_wrapper);
final DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            drawerLayout,
            null,
            R.string.nullable,
            R.string.nullable
    ) {};

    drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);


 mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                drawerLayout,
                null,
                R.string.nullable,
                R.string.nullable
        ) {};

        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);


    drawerLayout.setClickable(false);
    drawerLayout.setEnabled(false);
    drawerLayout.setFocusable(false);
    drawerLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    drawerLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    });
```

what I want is to disable click on `drawerLayout` layout in order to manage it programmatically. So, need to ignore normal behaviours.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the indicator:

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```